# Not able to view grid lines in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a schema, but in Workbench when I add a diagram it shows nothing. I've tried adding tables and nothing shows up. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagraming is part of modeling, so it will not affect your live database. Either use modeling then forward-engineer the model/diagram, or simply edit the database/schema with Workbench (and don't use modeling). The latter is simpler and more straight-forward.

Consider the FAQ entry titled [How do I create a MySQL database (schema) in MySQL Workbench?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-faq.html#faq-workbench-create-database)

Or if you're goal here is to use modeling, then consider the tutorial titled [Creating a Model](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html); and it also shows the forward-engineering procedure.